# File chooser in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener, jfilechooser

I am trying to use file chooser in my code, I am getting an error `"Not an enclosing class"` in `"int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);"`. Below is my code. ANy guesses to solve it?

```
browse_button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

     int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(FileChooserDemo.this);

      File file = fc.getSelectedFile();

                log.append("Opening: " + file.getAbsolutePath() + "." + "\n");
                String ab=file.getAbsolutePath();
                System.out.println(ab);

}});
```

I have made the `actionlistener` in main method.

Comment: Yes I have made a Jframe in whcich the browse_button is added.The idea is that when browse_button is clicked then file chooser should appear.

Comment: I think "fc" needs to be declared as final in the code before you create the action listener, or declared as a member field within the class

Comment: @Mad: No, `final` won't work here. If that were the issue, the error message would state this explicitly (as we've all experienced).

Comment: fc is already final in the code :/

Comment: @hovercraftfullofees yep, clutching a straws :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that you're making this call in a static method, `main(...)`, and are trying to use `FileChooserDemo.this` (a reference to the enclosing class) inside of this static method. Well this won't work because there is no `this` in the static world. The solution is to do this in non-static code such as a non-static method or the class's constructor.

Comment: Is there any way that i can use it in main method?rest of my code is also in main method.

Comment: Its giving the same error when I am using it in constructor :/

Comment: Ok I have got what i wanted. I only edited 
"int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(null);" . @Hovercraft Full Of Eels you were right. But I guess using "null" will work for mr for now. Thanks for the help guys...

Comment: @user841852: I would recommend that you not do this in the main method or any other static method. The main method should be very small and should just set up your main objects and get them started, that's it.